# Application running with RootviewController error- Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I do not know what is wrong with this method.I just created a new project and run it.It showing Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Specifically, what's the problem? Code there is no problem at all.

Comment: i am getting error as Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: what is your target os and xcode version?

Comment: os 10.6.8 and xcode 4.2

Comment: Are you have a `MainWindow.xib`?

Comment: remove please. tell me about next situation.

Comment: I wore the exact answer. There are two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a MainWindow.xib.

remove below line. do not remove MainWindow.xib

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

---

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

OR

do not remove above line. remove MainWindow.xib and Project Summary Main Interface set null.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

[image]